# NSNumber and MySQL NULL values

Tags: objective-c, null, nsnumber

I'm working on an Mac OS X application which deals with records from an **MySQL** database server.
I'm fetching data with the help of the **MySQL C API** and create an **NSMutableArray** for the result. Each fetched record creates an **NSDictionary**, which is added to the **NSMutableArray**.

What is the best way to handle empty number values returned by the database server?
Since nil can't be inserted into an **NSDictionary**, I tried several solutions like associated objects to "mark" an **NSNumber** as **NULL**, using **[NSNull null]**, or even subclassing **NSNumber**. But the most simple solution I found was creating an **NSNumber** with a double value of zero divided by zero, like this:

```
// for each row in the MySQL result check the field type and create the ObjC value
...
case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE: {
  if (row[col] == NULL) {   // row is the last fetched MYSQL_ROW
    [record setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0/0.0] forKey:columnNames[col]];
  } else {
    [record setObject:@(strtod(row[col], NULL)) forKey:columnNames[col]];
  }
  break;
}
...
```

This allows for an easy test against NSDecimalNumber's notANumber property and also the use of
NSNumberFormatter's notANumberSymbol to format empty values in the UI.

Are there any drawbacks to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

I would create the NaN number different:

```
[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]
```

The division by zero leads to an undefined state, if I remember the standard correct.

But beside this I think, that it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an associative array, you don't need to set it as nil, skipping over the key instead will result in the returned object for that key being nil, which takes less code to compare as opposed to notANumber. Like so:

```
 case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE: {
    if (row[col])
      [record setObject:@(strtod(row[col], NULL)) forKey:columnNames[col]];
    }
    break;
```

}

Comment: I have to assign a value for all columns. Bindings will work with nil, but observerValueForKeyPath: will not.